# Detect if running servlet container is Eclipse Jetty

Tags: eclipse, jetty, detection

I try to detect if the application is running on Eclipse Jetty as servlet container. I found a [solution for Mortbay Jetty](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/src/00456bde03353c5dbcfffdb77407f319c918bd51/scm-core/src/main/java/sonia/scm/ServletContainerDetector.java?at=default) , but not for the actual version from Eclipse. I modified the existing check and replaced the Classpath from "/org/mortbay/jetty/Server.class" to "/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.class" but the check fails on Jetty 9. Running the same application on tomcat was successful. What did I wrong?

The code looks like:

```java
private boolean detect(final String clazz) {
  try {
    final ClassLoader systemClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    systemClassLoader.loadClass(clazz);
    return true;
  } catch (final ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    final Class<?> classObj = getClass();
      if (classObj.getResource(clazz) != null) {
        return true;
  } else {
        return false;
      }
  }
}
```

Function called with:

```java
detect("/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.class");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the server class can be done from embedded mode, but not a standalone Jetty.
This is because the WebAppClassloader isolates access to the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server` class to webapps.

However, you can use the fact that all servlet container must have an implementation of the `default` servlet, just use the [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) to access the [RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) for the default servlet and pay attention to the implementation class name. Seems to work well on both Jetty 8.1.10 and 9.0.3 during embedded use. (will try again on standalone jetty shortly)

Full class as example:

```java
package com.company.foo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/detect" })
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DetectServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        detect(out,"org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server");
        detect(out,"/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.class");
        detect(out,"org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request");
        detect(out,"/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.class");
        detect(out,"org.mortbay.jetty.Server");
        detect(out,"/org/mortbay/jetty/Server.class");

        detectDefaultServlet(out, req, "org.eclipse.jetty");
        detectDefaultServlet(out, req, "org.apache.catalina");

        String version = getReflectedMethodValue("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server", "getVersion");
        out.printf("Server.getVersion() = %s%n", version);
    }

    private void detectDefaultServlet(PrintWriter out, HttpServletRequest req, String keyword)
    {
        // Request the default servlet (its pretty safe to say it will always be there)
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("default");
        if(dispatcher == null) {
            out.printf("detectDefaultServlet(out, req, \"%s\") = <no default servlet>%n", keyword);
            return;
        }

        // If the request dispatcher implementation contains the keyword, we can claim a match
        boolean detected = dispatcher.getClass().getName().contains(keyword);
        out.printf("detectDefaultServlet(out, req, \"%s\") = %b (%s)%n", keyword, detected, dispatcher.getClass().getName());
    }

    private String getReflectedMethodValue(String clazzName, String methodName)
    {
        ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        try
        {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(clazzName,false,loader);
            Class<?> parameterTypes[] = new Class<?>[0];
            Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName,parameterTypes);
            Object args[] = new Object[0];
            return (String)method.invoke(clazz,args);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            return "<class-not-found>";
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            return "<" + t.getClass().getName() + ": " + t.getMessage() + ">";
        }
    }

    private void detect(PrintWriter out, String resource)
    {
        out.printf("detect(\"%s\") = %b%n",resource,detected(resource));
    }

    private boolean detected(String clazz)
    {
        try
        {
            ClassLoader systemClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

            systemClassLoader.loadClass(clazz);

            return true;
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
        {
            Class<?> classObj = getClass();

            if (classObj.getResource(clazz) != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which will produce the following output on Jetty 8.1.10 **Embedded**

```
detect("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server") = true
detect("/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.class") = true
detect("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request") = true
detect("/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.class") = true
detect("org.mortbay.jetty.Server") = false
detect("/org/mortbay/jetty/Server.class") = false
detectDefaultServlet(out, req, "org.eclipse.jetty") = true (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher)
detectDefaultServlet(out, req, "org.apache.catalina") = false (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher)
Server.getVersion() = 8.1.10.v20130312
```

And similar output on Jetty 9.0.3 **Embedded**

```
detect("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server") = true
detect("/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.class") = true
detect("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request") = true
detect("/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.class") = true
detect("org.mortbay.jetty.Server") = false
detect("/org/mortbay/jetty/Server.class") = false
detectDefaultServlet(out, req, "org.eclipse.jetty") = true (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher)
detectDefaultServlet(out, req, "org.apache.catalina") = false (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher)
Server.getVersion() = 9.0.3.v20130506
```

But different for Jetty 9.0.3 **Standalone**

```
detect("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server") = false
detect("/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.class") = false
detect("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request") = false
detect("/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.class") = false
detect("org.mortbay.jetty.Server") = false
detect("/org/mortbay/jetty/Server.class") = false
detectDefaultServlet(out, req, "org.eclipse.jetty") = true (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher)
detectDefaultServlet(out, req, "org.apache.catalina") = false (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher)
Server.getVersion() = <class-not-found>
```

Comment: Come to think of it, you could use any Servlet interface and see if the implementation class name starts with `"org.eclipse.jetty."`